# Where can I get the database files in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have a MacBook Air and want to remove Outlook from it. I cannot do am export as I don't have enough hard drive space, and also cannot export over a network.

Where can I find the OLM files as with Outlook for Windows where the PST is already created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained [on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Where-does-Mac-Outlook-2011-store-its-data-files):

> Outlook stores only the indices in the Database (with a capital “D”) file and stores the data records as a series of files nested within folders. The Database file and its folders are located here:
>
> - ~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Database
> - ~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/Data Records

Comment: In the future, please include the relevant parts here, on site. We don't like answers that only consist of links.

Answer (score 1):

In Office for Mac 2015/2016/365, the location has changed to:

`~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile`

Answer (score 0):

This location has change for Office for Mac 2016 see http://www.officeformachelp.com/2015/04/location-of-outlook-2016-profile-identity/